# I keep on having problems with syntax and calculating the roots of the quadratic equation

Tags: python

Hey I am having problems with calculating the roots of the quadratic equation with the quadratic formula, using python's complex number functionality.

When I try

```
>>> if root<0:
        root=abs(complex(root))
        j=complex(0,1)
        x1=(-b+sqrt(root))/2*a
        x2=(-b-j+sqrt(root))/2*a
        else:
```

I get the error message

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Then, when I try instead

```
>>> if root<0:
        root=abs(complex(root))
        j=complex(0,1)
        x1=(-b+j+sqrt(root))/2*a
        x2=(-b-j+sqrt(root))/2*a
        break
```

I get the error

> SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

I am trying to put:

```
else:
    x1=(-b+j+sqrt(root))/2*a
    x2=(-b-j+sqrt(root))/2*a
```

under it but it won't work.

Any help please?

Comment: i had to edit your mess so much that i suspect i may have fixed whatever problem you had or simply messed things up beyond recognition.  can you check the above and see if it still shows your problem and, if not, either close this or change as needed?

Comment: first tell me if `6/2*3` is the same as `6/(2*3)`

Comment: @Andrew, You edited out the errors he was getting, and now his question is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your problem, but it looks like you are not properly indenting -- Python uses white space to mark blocks, so the above should look like:

```
if root<0:
    root=abs(complex(root))
    j=complex(0,1)
    x1=(-b+j+sqrt(root))/2*a
    x2=(-b-j+sqrt(root))/2*a
else:
    x1=(-b+j+sqrt(root))/2*a
    x2=(-b-j+sqrt(root))/2*a
```

although that doesn't make sense because `x1` and `x2` are calculated the same in both branches, and `j` is not defined in the `else` branch...  so maybe what you really want is

```
if root<0:
    root=abs(complex(root))
j=complex(0,1)
x1=(-b+j+sqrt(root))/2*a
x2=(-b-j+sqrt(root))/2*a
```

Part of my confusion is the prompt: `enter code here` -- this is not a standard Python prompt so either you changed your prompt or you are using some other program with your Python.  At any rate, hope this helps.

Comment: `enter code here` is what SO gives you when you want to enter a code block (pressing Ctrl-K)... Lando just didn't realize that it meant "replace this with your code" and added his code behind it (fixed in the current revision of the question)

Answer (score 1):

try importing the complex math module, available online in a number of forms. I believe there is an implementation for complex numbers in the standard python distributions, as well as in numpy/scipy. You can also try working out the real and complex components of your roots separately (by including a test based on the value of the discriminant). Also, your if and elif tests are identical.

Answer (score 0):

As @bythenumbers points out, your if and elif conditions are the same.  Also, are you getting exceptions or the wrong values?  Also also, where you have `j+sqrt(root)`, do you perhaps mean `j*sqrt(root)`?